# How can I change operators styling/shortening in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, operators, ligature

I'm wondering how I can prevent conditional operators like `!==` from looking like this:

[image]

I just want them to look like `<=` `>=` etc. as I read them easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "operators styling/shortening" are called **Ligatures**. Writing style makes reading easy and convenient and can make your editor look better with awesome fonts along with ligatures.

Check out your **settings.json** in VSC for:

```
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

If you want to turn off font ligatures for a specific programming language (ex. PHP), than add this lines to a **settings.json** file in VSC:

```
{
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "[php]": {
    "editor.fontLigatures": false
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I believe i turned it on at one point to give it a go but didnt know which settings to turn it off. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score -2):

These are called ["ligatures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). If you want to enable or disable ligatures on a fine-grained basis, consult your font's documentation to see whether and how it is supported. VS Code supports configuring font ligatures in the same way as browsers do via CSS (since VS Code is browser-based): [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings#syntax) in its `editor.fontLigatures` setting.

For example, for Fira Code, see [its readme](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#whats-in-the-box). Its equality operator ligatures are controlled by `ss08`. Its other comparison operators are controlled by `ss02`, `cv19`, `cv20`, `cv23`.

If you want to completely disable ligatures, set `editor.fontLigatures` to `false`.